# D3 Pack Layout translate paths on zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to combine a [D3](http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/) [Pack Layout](https://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html) with links. It works in the initial state but when I try to zoom the positions of the svg path elements are not updated. How can I translate paths such that they are aligned to the nodes when the user performs zooming? Below is my zoom function.
To check the whole code, see [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqp5ngLv/1/). I hope somebody can help me!

```
function zoom(d, i) {
    var k = r / d.r / 2;
    x.domain([d.x - d.r, d.x + d.r]);
    y.domain([d.y - d.r, d.y + d.r]);

    var t = vis.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750);

    t.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return y(d.y);
        })
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return k * d.r;
        });

    t.selectAll("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y);
        })
        .style("opacity", function(d) {
            return k * d.r > 20 ? 1 : 0;
        });

    console.log(t.selectAll('path'));
    d3.selectAll('path')
        .attr('class', function() {
            // TODO: diversify
            return 'child-branch';
        })
        .style('stroke', function(d) {
            return d3.rgb(d3.scale.category20(d.target.by_alliance_with + 1)).darker();
        })
        .attr('d', function(d) {
            console.log("d", d);
            return linkArc(d);
        });
```

Comment: I managed to solve it. See the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jqp5ngLv/2/)